# How can I stop a program on another computer using CMD with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to stop Pulse Secure before uninstalling it and installing a newer version using Powershell

In CMD from a computer you can type this to stop it:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\JamUI\Pulse.exe" -stop
```

But I can't seem to get it stopped from Powershell. I've tried a few different variants, but can't seem to get it.

```
$PC = (Read-Host "Enter Computer Name").ToUpper()
ICM $PC {& cmd.exe /c '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\JamUI\Pulse.exe" -stop'}
```

.

```
$PC = (Read-Host "Enter Computer Name").ToUpper()
$STOP = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\JamUI\Pulse.exe"
ICM $PC {& cmd.exe /c "$STOP -stop"}
```

The second option returns '-stop' is not recognized as an internal or external command... Any suggestions or better ways to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
invoke-command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock {Stop-process -name Pulse -force}
```

This did it.